# Implement notifications on android in 4g

Tags: java, android, sockets, service

I'm stuck with the notification's thing. I make my own API which insert some events in a database, but also I want to notify the users when one of these events happen.

First, I try to implement my own notification system with a service and sockets. The thing was has a socket listening, but the problem is that the internet providers block incoming connections, then I can not use that way to achieve my goal.

After that, I thought to make requests, with volley, to the API in intervals of 5 minutes. But that way doesn't look very optimal in terms of performance.....correct me if I'm wrong

A lot of people recommend to use Firebase but, It gives me a lot of doubts.
I am forced to use Firebase? Applications like WhatsApp, Instagram, Facebook... etc also use Firebase because there is no other way?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Implementing an own push notification system is pretty hard and will cost al lot of battery power on the device. If you need an example check out source code of Signal Android app. They have implemented notification system that does not base on Google cloud/firebase messaging system.

Comment: thanks, @Robert. I checked out the source code of the signal project. I've noticed that it's too big for me at the moment..... I think I will use a third party notification service. pd: Checking the dependencies of the signal project, I found: // Firebase
            alias('firebase-messaging').to('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'), they use it for something

Answer (score 0):

there are many push notification service that you can use here is a link [push notification services](https://www.mobiloud.com/blog/best-push-notification-services) .As long as i know ,telegram uses firebase push notification.While you have many options to implement push notification in your app i suggest you to use firebase because its free, easy to use and etc.Also firebase is one of googles services so its reliable and developer friendly.There is just one problem with firebase, you shouldnt use it to transfer important data because sometimes there is a delay between the request you send and the notification you receive.You can also build your own service from scratch if you have the requirements but its just waste of time

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).